# Why is my Premiere timeline scrollbar thumb non-proportional?

Tags: premiere

In almost every app on Earth, the width of the scrollbar thumb (aka scroller or knob) is proportional to the amount of content present in the window, relative to total content.

Yet in Premiere Pro CS6, it seems to follow a totally different logic. For example, in this simple one-clip timeline, I'm scrolled all the way to the left, and the clip pretty much fills the timeline.

[image]

But dragging the scroller right just a little bit (as seen below), the clip flies offscreen, even though the scroller area is clearly overlapping its previous area.

[image]

What's up with that?? Is my install bugged, or is this just a bizarre UI oversight by Adobe?

**UPDATE: More screengrabs and descriptions**

The image below shows 4 states:
1) Fully zoomed out. TONS of empty space.
2) Zoomed to fill the timeline with the clip.
3) Scrolling until the end of the clip is just in sight.
4) Scrolling all the way right.

[image]

The scrollers of states 2 & 3 have a 50% overlap, which means the clip should also be ~50% visible. It seems like Premiere thinks the timeline is twice as big as it actually is, as demonstrated by the 50% overlap. I was using dual-monitors, so I thought perhaps my dual-monitor setup was the cause, but disconnecting the 2nd prior to Fred Rick's reset didn't help.

Any more suggestions out there?

Comment: What happens if you drag the end of the scroll bar out to zoom out all the way?  What does it look like then?  Have you had any other clips in the sequence or had that clip further down the sequence earlier?

Comment: Thanks for asking :) I've added a screenshot of the fully zoomed out state. There were not clips in the sequence earlier.

Comment: are you sure it added?  I don't see any edits in the last 16 hours.

Comment: i commented you while finishing the post :)

Answer (score 2):

Well this is not my Direct Answer but tried this?:

trash the preferences and then create a new project. Then go to window>workspace and uncheck the import workspace from the project and reset it again. Then try opening your project and check.

My Buddy Google gave me that:
http://forums.adobe.com/message/5796914

Cheers

Comment: This looks like it is for when the scrollbar is missing from the workspace entirely.

Comment: I just tried this to the letter, and the problem persists. Thanks for the great suggestion!